# NodeJs whitelisting Ips for a particular URL In Google App Engine not working?

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, whitelist

I am trying to whitelist an IP address for my Google `App Engine`, I am currently using [express-ipfilter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-ipfilter) for whitelisting selected Ip's, but the thing is, it is not working as from whichever IP I will hit, my API `express-ipfilter` is always showing

> Access denied to IP address: 172.XX.X.X

There is also a `firewall-rules` section in `App Engine` but there is no option for providing the URL for the API which I am doing whitelisting?

I think this error is coming because as App Engine uses `Nginx` Behind the Web Server, also Ip Address coming is (`172.XX.X.X`)(Which means Ip is `Public` to Google Cloud).

Is there any inbuilt Google App Engine feature for whitelisting, or why my `express-ipfilter` is not working. Can anyone Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the thing is In App Engine requests does not comes directly to App Engine therefore in order to see the IP of the client we have to look for `req.get("X-Forwarded-For")` Header field, it is an array of Ip's so we have to check the first IP which is the client IP and if that matches the desired IP then we can do our work.

See the documentation here [nodejs/reference/request-headers](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/reference/request-headers)